# Simular Click em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu achei um código que simula o click de um botão, mas eu preciso chamar uma função em javascript e passar uma string, como ficaria isso ?

```html
document.getElementById("meuElemento").click();
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer? Sabes o que é `addEventListener`? explica o que queres fazer para ficar mais claro

Comment: não sei se é isso que você quer mas, para chamar uma função clicando no botão coloque isso na sua tag `button` `onclick="funcao('string passada')"`, e no javascript coloquei a função assim `function funcao(recebestring) `

Comment: @abduzeedo queres que a função seja chamada quando houver um clique ou queres fazer um clique porque chamaste uma função?

Comment: @abduzeedo eu quero perceber e ajudar mas nem eu nem os 3 que deram resposta parecem ter acertado/percebido. Podes dar mais exemplos/explicação a ver se fica claro para nós?

Comment: ok, Eu tenho um botão na minha pagina, o ID deste botão é MeuBotao, ok. Eu quero que o visitante não precise clicar neste botão, eu quero que um script javascript dispare o evento ONCLICK deste botão de forma automatica, filtrando pelo ID do botão

Answer (score 1):

coloque assim:

```
  <a href="#" id="meuElemento" onclick="funcao('minha string')">clique aqui.</a>

        <script>
            function funcao(string) {
                alert(string)
            }
            document.getElementById("meuElemento").click();
        </script>
```

Comment: é isso, o document.getElement está simulando o click. no click do link há a funcao que passa uma string. dentro da funcao vc manipula a string.

Comment: vou editar pra ficar mais facil pra vc entender.

Comment: testa la brother

Answer (score 1):

Você pode chamar a função diretamente também:

```js
function evento(string){
  console.log(string);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="meuElemento" onclick="evento('Teste')">
```